# Find duplicates from 2 different integer array using stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 different integer arrays:

```
int arr1[] = [1,2,3,4]
int arr2[] = [2,3,5,6]
```

How to find duplicates from the above 2 arrays using the Stream API of Java 8?

In Java 7 I have done;

```
    public class FindDuplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int arr2[] = {2, 3, 5, 6};

        // Using two loops to find duplicates
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                    System.out.println("Duplicate: " + arr1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a low/no effort question. Please edit your question to include what you've tried so far.

Comment: There is no reason to use the Stream API for that.

Comment: I was asked to use stream api only, without stream api i know how to do but using stream api i dont

Comment: the logic is the same as when you don't use streams. If you know how to do it without streams, you should be able to figure out how to do (or at least try) it with streams

Comment: Convert both to sets, and then use a stream to filter elements of a set that are in the other?

Answer (score 1):

- Convert both arrays to a stream.
- Use filter() to keep only the elements of arr1 that are also present in arr2.
- Collect the results to a list.

  ```
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.stream.Collectors;
  public class duplicate {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
      int[] arr2 = {2, 3, 5, 6};

      List<Integer> duplicates = Arrays.stream(arr1)
              .boxed()
              .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(arr2).anyMatch(j -> j == i))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

      System.out.println(duplicates);   

  }
  ```

The output

[image]

In the above code:

`Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed()` converts the int array arr1 to a stream of Integer objects.

The `filter()` method keeps only those numbers from arr1 that are also present in arr2.
The `collect()` method collects the result into a list.

**Another way is:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
     int[] arr2 = {2, 3, 5, 6};
        Set<Integer> set1 = IntStream.of(arr1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Integer> intersection = IntStream.of(arr2).boxed()
                                          .filter(set1::contains)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println("Duplicated elements: " + intersection);
}
```

1. **IntStream.of(arr1).boxed()**:

   - `IntStream.of(arr1)`: This creates an `IntStream` (a stream of `int` values) from the `arr1` array.
   - `.boxed()`: This converts the `IntStream` (stream of primitive `int`s) to a `Stream<Integer>` (stream of `Integer` objects).
2. **collect(Collectors.toSet())**:

   - The `collect` method is a terminal operation that transforms the elements of the stream into a different kind of result or a mutable reduction.
   - `Collectors.toSet()` is a collector that accumulates input elements into a new `Set`. So, after `boxed()`, it collects the `Integer` objects into a `Set<Integer>`.
3. **.filter(set1::contains)**:

   - The `filter` method is an intermediate operation that allows you to filter elements from the stream based on a predicate.
   - `set1::contains`: This is a method reference to the `contains` method of `set1`. It means each element of `IntStream.of(arr2).boxed()` will be passed to the `contains` method of `set1` to check if it's present in `set1`. If it's present, it means it's a common element between `arr1` and `arr2`.

Comment: please don't just spoonfeed code.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency I suggest using set for caching. Below code is O(n + m) (where n and m are lengths of arr1 and arr2)

```
    int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int arr2[] = {2, 3, 5, 6};

    //convert arr2 to Set for later quick O(1) lookup
    Set<Integer> set2 = Arrays
            .stream(arr2) // Turn arr2 into IntStream
            .boxed() // boxed() converts IntStream to Stream<Integer>
                     //  this is needed because Set can only hold objects
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Collect all incoming Integer objects into a Set (HashSet<Integer>)
    
    //filter arr1 elements that exist in the set2 (arr2)
    Set<Integer> duplicates = Arrays.stream(arr1) // Turn arr1 into IntStream 
            .boxed()    // boxed() converts IntStream to Stream<Integer>
                        //  this is needed because set2::contains expects an Integer object
            .filter(set2::contains) // Filter out all elements that are not in set2 (*)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Collect all incoming Integer objects into a Set (HashSet<Integer>) for final results

    System.out.println(duplicates);
```

(*) `set2::contains` is a method reference, it is equivalent to the lambda expression `(x) -> set2.contains(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a set to filter like this:

```
    int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4};
    int[] arr2 = {2,3,4,5,6};

    Set<Integer>  uniqueItems = new HashSet<>();
    List<Integer> dupplicates = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed(), Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed())
          .filter(i -> !uniqueItems.add(i))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if an element is already in a set the call to uniqueItems.add(i) will return false.